# Creating labels that are on top of another div

Tags: html, css

I'm in the process of creating a user dashboard and would like to have labels with a number count for each label. What I'm trying to accomplish can be seen in the image below.

[image]

I'm using flaticon.com icons with either bootstraps "label" or "badge" style.

Could one of you skilled inviduals point me in the right direction.

Here's what mine looks like.

[image]

And here is my code (HTML & CSS):

```
<span class="flaticon-cloudstorage10 lg"><span class="label label-default">2</span></span>

.label.label-default {
position: absolute;
text-align: center;
top: 9px;
right: 7px;
padding: 2px 3px;
line-height: .9;
}

.flaticon-cloudstorage10.lg:before {
font-size: 20px;
padding-left: 10px;
position: relative;
}
```

Here's what I get after adding position: relative to the flaticon.

[image]

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Create a demo of your current output please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is the css properties of flaticon-cloudstorage10 lg?

does it have {position:relative;} ? If not, you can try to put give it that property.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to add position:relative to the div that was holding my flaticon's and not to the icons themselves. Thank you JKC for pointing me in the right direction.

Here's the final look.

[image]